# Passing a structure with a callback from React Native to a native view

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Is there a way to pass a complex structure containing a callback function from React Native to a native iOS view as a property? E.g. a structure like this:

```
[
  {
    'type': 'some type',
    'callback': this.someCallback
  },
  {
    'type': 'another type',
    'callback': this.anotherCallback
  }
]
```

For such a structure the callbacks are passed like empty dictionaries.

Comment: you cant not send a call base but you can listen to ```DeviceEventEmitter``` for sync up. additionally you can use ```NativeModules.EventHook``` to send data and/or receive data. i believe there is not real time call back but only can listen to lifecycle events of app.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are not serializable and therefore cannot be passed over the React Native bridge.

A native UI component can have a event property which is essentially a block that you can call on the native side and will be received as a callback prop on the representing JS component.

For example:

```
//native property
@property (nonatomic, copy) RCTBubblingEventBlock onSomeEvent;

//native usage
if(self.onSomeEvent) {
    self.onSomeEvent(@{@"myParam": @"param_value"});
}

//JS side
<MyView onSomeEvent={params => console.log('got params', params)}/>
```